# How to filter all Unpublished blog posts in Sitefinity v9.1?

Tags: sitefinity

How to add Unpublished filter in this section for blog posts?
[image: filter posts screenshot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to do the following steps.

Please navigate to **Administration->Settings->Advanced->Blogs->Controls->PostsBackend->Views->PostsBackendList->Sidebar->Sections->FilterPosts->Items**.

Click **Create new** and select option **CommandWidgetElement**.
Fill the following fields with the corresponding values:

**Command name** - filter

**Command argument** - {filterExpression : "ApprovalWorkflowState = \"Unpublished\""}

**Command button type** - SimpleLinkButton

**Defines restriction level** - Default

**Name** - UnpublishedPosts

**CommandText** - UnpublishedPosts

**WrapperTagName** - Unknown

**Type** - Telerik.Sitefinity.Web.UI.Backend.Elements.Widgets.CommandWidget, Telerik.Sitefinity

The other fields should be empty.

Click **Save changes**.

Now you should have UnpublishedPosts option in the blog posts sidebar.

Here are some links to prove the steps.
[Video with steps for pages.](http://www.screencast.com/t/F5paJvvidU) and [Thread with some info.](http://www.sitefinity.com/developer-network/forums/general-discussions-/add-a-filter-option-to-the-images-library)